# R select column by name: dataframe$x returns NULL

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a Data frame that I want to draw all the values out of column by column identified by column name. The code below just returns five NULL values where five is the number of columns in my Data frame

```
for(x in names(DataFrame)){
  print(DataFrame$x)
}
```

This is the simplified version, but the ultimate goal is a shiny app that turns individual columns into selectInput boxes with this function. I can then modify the number of input boxes just by changing the spreadsheet. Seen below

```
for(x in names(DataFrame)){
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
       selectInput(paste("Input","x"), h5("x"),
                   choices= DataFrame$x)))}
```

In short, I want the DataFrame$x to return a list of the things in each column. Now it's returning NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are trying to print the values in a column named `x`. If you want to link to a column using a name (`string`) you should but the `string` between brackets.

```
for(x in names(DataFrame)){
    print(DataFrame[[x]])
}
```